# I have an error in my PHP code set up to view my images

Tags: php, image

```
    <?php   
    $con=mysql_connect ("xxx","xxx","xxx");
    mysql_select_db("dbhappps",$con);
    @$sql="select * from tbl_image where id='4' and status='0'";
    @$query=mysql_query($sql);
    while(@$row=mysql_fetch_array($query))
    {
    @$image=$row ['photo'];
    echo $image

   ?>
   <img src="/image/<?php echo $image; ?>" width="320" height="480">
   <?php
   }
   ?>
```

The echo $image is giving me the correct file name so I am either not referencing the /image (the image folder is in my root directory) folder correctly or could it be a browser issue? I am testing it in google chrome. any tips would be great.

Comment: what does the post-processing source look like

Comment: it looks like a broken image.

Comment: `echo $image` you didn't close echo. Right syntax `echo $image;`

Comment: the source, not the page itself.

Comment: Browser version doesn't matter, but adding the error suppressors isn't helping you, in case something is in fact throwing an error.

Comment: check the browser source to see what was echoed. See if you can navigate it from inside the source

Comment: @warlord, it wasn't working before I put that echo $image in there.

Comment: If the src starts with `/image` then it is DocumentRoot (or "site") relative, rather than system root relative. What is the DocumentRoot? You can also change the path to start with `file:///` to actually make it system root relative if that is really what you want.

Comment: @warlord - you don't need the semicolon there in the actual tag, neither do you need it in the while loop as there isn't any PHP after that line.  this is most likely a file path issue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**try this**

```
<img src="//yourwebsite.com/image/<?php echo $image; ?>" width="320" height="480">
```

Replace yourwebsite with your website name. or localhost/test etc.
Also check that you are getting .jpg .gif. jpeg extension in the last. other wise use this

```
<img src="//yourwebsite.com/image/<?php echo $image; ?>.jpg" width="320" height="480">
```

Answer (score 1):

View source in the browser and see if there are any unneeded spaces etc. Also just right click on the image and copy image url and paste in browser to check if the image really does exist. I think its a path issue more than a browser issue.

Comment: using Developer tools in either Firefox or Chrome is another way to check to see if the resource exists